# Any readable, working Flex+BlazeDS+Spring+GAE (storing more than one table in GAE Datastore) tutorial?

Tags: java, apache-flex, spring, google-app-engine, blazeds

I need a readable tutorial on working with Flex+BlazeDS+Spring+GAE (storing more than one table in GAE Datastore). Is there any such?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to go step by step:

http://www.springsource.org/spring-flex (covers BlazeDS and Flex with Spring)

http://sikeh.javaeye.com/blog/364043 (covers Google App Engine and Spring)

Answer (score 0):

i  tried to run a blazds-flex app on Google App Engine but it didnt  rn, I have read about it and i found that there are some changes to make to blazeds java components to get the app running on the google plattform, i found some interesting info [here](http://martinzoldano.blogspot.com/2009/04/appengine-adobe-blazeds-fix.html)

Or for a more basic information about blaze-ds messaging info go to this asotto.blogspot.com .